# Is the Jolicloud DE still available and what versions does it work with?

Tags: chromium, desktop-environments, cloud, compatibility

Since it was my first Linux distro, I'm nostalgic about the now discontinued [Joli OS.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joli_OS)

I was delighted to [read here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/jolicloud-your-new-favourite-ubuntu-de) that the desktop environment has been forked/ported to Ubuntu.

That's a three years old article though. Is it still available, and which flavors/versions does it work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be available for Precise (ubuntu 12.04) which is still supported until April 2017.

There doesn't appear to be any packages for any newer releases.

Sources:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

https://launchpad.net/~jolicloud-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=

Comment: Today I learned that one person with  > 3k rep thought this was not about Ubuntu, and another one thought it was too broad.

Comment: @Fiksdal that's the beauty of governing by consensus. We don't have to always agree to get the job done.

Comment: Well said. SE works really well :)